# How exporting features to shapefile in javascript in zip file format?

Tags: javascript, zip, shapefile

I'm developing a web gis using [OpenLayer 3.18.1](http://openlayers.org). I have some features in [geojson](http://geojson.io) format. 
I want to export this features in shape file(in a single zip file) in client side using javascript.

**Is it possible**? if yes, **How**?

**Update**:

I found [js2shapefile](https://github.com/borisdev/js2shapefile) for creating shapefile. But this library has 2 difficulty:

1. Not create .prj file,
2. Not zip files(.shp, .shx & .dbf).

**There is no idea**?

Comment: you may use http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/

Comment: Main problem is exporting shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

You can view from https://github.com/aspetkov/cmv-widgets/tree/master/JS2Shapefile how to create a project file and how to export  shapefile in a single zip file without additional libraries.